# getline(cin, var) not working!

Tags: c++, string, recursion, getline

For some strange reason, the getline() function is not working as it should.  I have my program loop via recursion (return main();).  The first time the following code is run, it's fine.

```
cout << "Enter a phrase: ";
string user;
getline(cin, user);
```

However, after the recursion is invoked, the program skips the step that allows me to type.  The effect is that string user is empty.  Any ideas why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

call `cin.clear()` to clear any flags before looping around.

EDIT: Thanks to @Xeo for pointing out, should also call `cin.ignore()` to discard the new line character - which could still be in the buffer...

Comment: Might need a `cin.ignore` too since the newline is still in the buffer (at least that's the behaviour I always get).

Comment: if this is the problem, the solution may be to avoid the condition that sets the error flags in the first place.

Comment: It was my first though but getline() removes the delimitor (which default to \n) -- so ignore should not be needed -- and the only reason (excepted the UB due to the recursive call to main) for having a flag set is reaching EOF or trying to read more than string::max_size characters.

Answer (score 6):

A recursive call to main is not well defined in C++ (it is in C).  That may be or not the cause of your problem.

Comment: +1. It's surprising that a platform actually forbidding this would fail to issue a warning… but this is exactly the kind of symptom this would cause. `iostream` relies on global variables which may be getting reinitialized when `main` re-enters.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - really? how could that possibly be the case? I can understand that some stuff will be happening before the first call to `main`, but how can possibly be the case on subsequent calls - which are simply function calls? Furthermore, test with a normal recursive function that isn't called `main` and I'd hazard you have exactly the same problem...

Comment: +1 Exactly... it's legal for the compiler to inject whatever initialisation code/calls it likes at the start of `main()` (that makes it easier to create C++ systems for platforms where other entry points can't be defined for the executable object).  It may well be reinitialising the iostream's static variables (possibly with memory leaks or corruption), or it might be as Nim hopes and a simple clear() will work - but that only seems likely if if the recursion was basically safe for the implementation in question and a previous I/O operation had actually failed.

Comment: The technique some compilers use to make some stuff happen "before" main is to insert the code at the beginning of main.  That was the technique used by CFront, for example, and that is the reason why C++ doesn't allow recursive calls of `main`.  (But a compiler really could warn.)

Comment: @James, @Tony - well there you go, learned something new today... :)